# Is it possible to proxy a websocket connection from the client side?

Tags: logging, websocket

Here's the scenario. We have a webapp that communicates actions bidirectionally through websockets. I was wondering if it is possible to build a separate program (or use something existing) to "listen" in on the connection and log the messages of that link. Preferably it would be resident on the client side. Is this possible?

The idea is, we want to know every message that goes across the `ws` without having to modify either program to install this logging mechanism.

Comment: I'm thinking of sniffing packets that have src or dst as the server then log the packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. After a few days of playing around, you can use [`node-http-proxy`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to set up a proxy using node's socket library. This `npm` package also includes websocket proxying through HTTPS or HTTP.